# does it take the same energy to raise water from 10deg to 20deg as it does to raise it from 20-30 degrees?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Another way of putting it, is energy input linear per each degree of temperature (regardless of scale, Fahrenheit or Celsius)?  If not, is it either exponential or logarithmic?

As I don't see that tag available, I'm presuming this is a specific-heat related question.  Thanks.

Comment: Not quite. Heat capacity is weakly temperature dependent over most ranges between phase changes. The behavior is complex - something you look up from tables for various substances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The energy required to raise the temperature from $T_1$ to $T_2$ is:

$$ H = \int_{T_1}^{T_2} C(T)~dT \tag{1} $$

where $C(T)$ is the specific heat, which is generally a function of temperature.

In most cases the specific heat is almost constant because it changes only slightly with temperature. In that case equation (1) simplifies to:

$$ H = C\Delta T $$

where $\Delta T$ is the change in temperature. Note that this equation contains only the change in temperature and not the temperature itself. That means it does take *approximately* the same energy to raise water from $10$ºC to $20$ºC as it does to raise it from $20$ºC to $30$ºC, or indeed from $T$ to $T+10$ºC for any temperature $T$.

The variation of specific heat with temperature generally doesn't follow any simple law. In practice we compile tables of specific heat as a function of temperature by doing experimental measurements.

Comment: As a supplement for this great answer, see the values of specific heat (heat capacity) of water at the following link.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_(data_page)#Thermodynamic_properties